# Suppose $f$, $g$ are positive continuous functions on $[a,\infty)$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$, and $\int_a^{\infty}g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem Statement:**

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are positive, continuous functions defined on $[a,\infty)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $\int_a^{\infty}$ diverges (as an improper Riemann Integral). Show that at least one of the integrals

$$ \int_a^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx, \hspace{10mm} \int_a^{\infty} \dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}dx$$

diverges.

**My comments:**

Firstly, this is an old qualifying exam question for a Phd level real analysis where we have studied general Lebesgue Theory. For this problem I am thinking to assume that the first integral diverges, and show the other must converge. But besides that, I don't have any ideas about where to go from here. I would be happy with just a hint, and not a complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are meant to show that at least one diverges.  It could be that both diverge.  For example, if $f\equiv 1$.  If you start by assuming that one diverges, you are already doin' it wrong.  Ack.. fat-fingered the enter key... ugh...

Comment: Okay, yes that is a good point. I was wondering if my assumption there was wrong... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx&=\int_{a}^{\infty}\sqrt{f(x)g(x)}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{g(x)}}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx\\
&\leq\left(\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{\infty}\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}dx\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think it would be better to first integrate from $a$ to $b$ for some finite number $b$, and then take limit $b\to\infty$.

Comment: Since $g$ is continuous and nonnegative, the improper Riemann integral coincides with the Lebesgue one, so it is no problem to write that.